# TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: NoneType

Tags: python, django, spotify

```
File "C:\Users\rafae\Projects\Django and React Tuto\music_controller\spotify\util.py", line 22, in update_or_create_user_tokens
    expires_in = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=expires_in)
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: NoneType
```

Hey guys, getting this error when redirecting from spotify api and going back to my local server. Above is the error message and the location.
Below is the code inside models.py, determing the value of "expires_in":

```
class SpotifyToken(models.Model):
    ...
    expires_in = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error means `models.DateTimeField()` returned `None`, so that's the value of `expires_in`.  Nothing else to say since that's the only code you've shown.